# Does the Microsoft SQL Server native client support IDBAsynchNotify?

Tags: sql-server, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm working on some OLE DB code that runs queries on MS SQL Server via `ICommand::Execute`. I'm converting this code to operate asynchronously by setting the `DBPROPVAL_ASYNCH_INITIALIZE` property on the command before executing.

I'd prefer to register a `IDBAsynchNotify` sink so that my code can be notified of events, as opposed to polling or blocking via `ISSAsynchStatus`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718095%28VS.85%29.aspx) for `ICommand::Execute` does not show `IConnectionPointContainer` as an acceptable `riid` parameter, but the same document, when discussing the `DB_S_ASYNCHRONOUS` return code, suggests that it is possible to request an `IConnectionPointContainer` interface that I could use to register my event sink.

When I call `ICommand::Execute`, passing `IID_IConnectionPointContainer` as the `riid` parameter, I receive the `E_NOINTERFACE` error. I also tried setting the `DBPROP_IConnectionPointContainer` property before `Execute` but I received the same results.

If I have to, I'll use `ISSAsynchStatus`, but I'd much rather use `IDBAsynchNotify`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the response on [this SQL Server Native Client blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlnativeclient/sql-server-native-client-wants-to-hear-your-opinion), "asynchronous notification programming model" was the fifth most important feature that was requested for the native client. I guess that answers the question. Hopefully the sqlncli team will address this sooner rather than later. I am easily annoyed by polling.

Answer (score 0):

See [Performing Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131395%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for SQL Native Client OLE Db specifics, including examples. The link says the only acceptable RIIDs are IID_IDBAsynchStatus and IID_ISSAsynchStatus, so my understanding that is that the programming model is pool based, not notification based.

Comment: I'd read that document previously, and the behavior that I'm getting back from the code would certainly suggest this. I guess I'm curious as to whether any evidence exists that contradicts this.

Comment: I'm speculating here, but have you tried asking for IID_IUnknown and then QueryInterface on the result for IID_IConnectionPointContainer?

Comment: Bummer. I'm out of my element since OleDB was never a strong topic of mine, but I must say that async programming without callbacks doesn't fly too well...